# Poll() returns returncode = 0 from subprocess.Popen even if the command failed to complete, why?

Tags: python, subprocess

The code is borrowed from from here https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2015/01/getting-realtime-output-using-python/. Thx to Kannan Ponnusamy!

Anyway, I use this in a bioinformatics pipeline to get live feed what the program is doing and to be able to capture any error if it occurs.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            while process.poll() is None:
                print(process.stdout.readline())
            rc = process.poll()
            print("Returncode:",rc)
```

To raise an error, I tried to remove the file that the program tries to open.

[E::main_mem] fail to open file `/home/jonas/BASE/dna_seq/reads/2064-01//BHYHT7CCXY.RJ-1967-987-02.2_1.fastq'.

The problem is that poll() still returns returncode = 0. how can that be?

Comment: It's just a convention that a program returns a non-zero exit status if something went wrong.  Perhaps the program you're running doesn't obey that convention?

Comment: thx! you were right, I tried another program and that followed the convention...something  wrong with that program then:)

Comment: FYI the article you reference by Kannan Ponnusamy has moved here: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2015/01/getting-realtime-output-using-python/